# Dehydration after a nights sleep

Tags: sleep, water, headache, waking-up, dehydration

After a nights sleep I wake up with a headache which is slightly relieve after a drinking water although I still feel tired and fuzzy headed for the rest of the day.

The headaches started to occur after after I moved into a new build house. Our last house was colder and humid.   The new house is warmer and less humid.

Is it possible that warmer and dry air cause dehydration overnight? Can that cause morning headaches and fatigue during the day?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Personal medical advice is strictly off-topic here, but I've tried to make your question more general. If you disagree, you can roll back to your original post.

Comment: No, thats fine.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you know where i should post this to get help?

Comment: Well I hope someone on health SE can give a general answer (not exactly my area, so I'd have to do more research than usual to answer). The other option is to consult a physician, which is always the best thing to do to get personal medical advice. Without trying to answer in comments, I would like to point out that moving to another building doesn't mean just changing the temperature and humidity, but it could also mean different materials and paint in the house, different levels of noise etc. If these headaches are a regular occurrence for a certain amount of time (say a week or two) ...

Comment: [cont] I'd consult a doctor in person regardless of the answer you get here.

Comment: Does your home have a carbon monoxide detector?

Comment: Just came across this while browsing the app. It was migraine i was having and i corrected it by eating keto.